# Is it possible to link sometimes pad from outside of on-pad-added callback?

Tags: c++, gstreamer

Question same as in topic, is it possible to link sometimes pad from for example decodebin element to some other, compatible element's pad?

I'm trying to do something like this:

```
GstElement *decodebin = gst_element_factory_make( "decodebin", nullptr );
GstPad *pad = gst_pad_new( nullptr, GST_PAD_SRC );
gst_element_add_pad( decodebin, pad );
gst_bin_add( GST_BIN(pipeline), decodebin );

GstElement *videoconvert = gst_element_factory_make( "videoconvert", nullptr );
gst_bin_add( GST_BIN(pipeline), videoconvert );

gst_element_link( decodebin, videoconvert );
```

Strangely gst_element_link call is successful, thus I thought elements were linked fine. However when trying to run a pipeline I get an general stream error from h264parse element (which is located within decodebin as I presume), reason: not linked.
I've managed to make the pipeline work by linking those pads from within on-pad-added callback, however it seems unhandy to create a new callback function for each element with sometimes pads that I need to use.

Comment: What's elem in the code above? decodebin?

Comment: sorry, i've changed the name from elem --> decodebin and missed that one.

Comment: [article](http://www.jonobacon.org/2006/11/03/gstreamer-dynamic-pads-explained/) - article about how dynamic pads work using decodebin example. I find it quite useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What will happen is that your newly added pad to decodebin is linked to videoconvert. However this pad is not known to decodebin and will not provide any data, while the pads that decodebin will add itself will produce data but are not linked to anything (thus leading to a not-linked error).

You can link outside the pad-added callback to sometimes pads, but in the common case you need to block the pad in the pad-added callback to prevent it from outputting data which would lead to a not-linked error. Then later you can link to that sometimes pad and unblock it. See gst_pad_add_probe() (in 1.x, in 0.10 it was gst_pad_set_blocked*()).

Alternatively you can use gst_parse_launch() or gst_parse_bin_from_description() with "decodebin ! videoconvert", which will automatically do the delayed linking from the pad-added signal.

Comment: So what you're saying is that decodebin is not using the pad i've added at all, instead it creates it's own sometimes pad which produces entire output?

Comment: Yes, or it creates even multiple own pads if there are multiple streams (e.g. one audio and one video stream).

Comment: You are not supposed to add pads to elements yourself like this, only the elements themselves do that unless we're talking about request pads (but those are requested via special API)